# Format number type long into 8 digits

Tags: c#, performance, casting

I have two variables of type `long?`. I need to use long1 variable and, if null, take long2.

```
//long1 format: 20130104
//long2 format: 2.01301071520553E16

var target = long1 ?? long2;
```

The variable target will be used in a query to find an exact match with a varibale in format "xxxxxxxx" (8 digits, same format as long1).

Is there any elegant way to *cut* the long2 digits into the same format as long1 without having to parse it into a string first? 
Since I will have to process the target variable as long and not a string, therefore I would avoid a second parse from string to long again.

Comment: What is the type of the variable you are comparing to? Is it a string? `long` does not have a "format"!

Comment: Formatting only happens on _display_. `long`s do not have an associated "format", as such.

Comment: I would use string.Format, but my question was about if anyone knows a better way to change the format/length of the long variable without having to parse it into a string and then again into a long.

Comment: @Jon: the variable type is "long?" (first line of the question).

Answer (score 0):

Just take as many digits of accuracy as you require when you print the variable later on.  It doesn't matter if it has 100 digits, it's only used for calculations.  When you are ready to display it use:

```
String.Format("MyLong: {0:0.00000000}", long);
```

Or however you want it to look.

Comment: I would like to avoid having to convert it into a string, since I have to use the variable as long and this would imply to make 2 cast in order to adjust the format.